# image textures won't show (on mesh which was a curve before)

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, bezier-curves

I am trying to add some wood pbr-materials on some simple objects. I made some of these objects out of curves, which I later converted into meshes and then just filled them up and made them thicker in editmode.
**Now:** When I try to add image textures to these objects, only the average colour of the image would show, not even with one detail. Other objects with the same material but which are made out of simple cubes, work perfectly.

How do I make the imagetextures work on meshes, which where (bezier-)curves before, too?

[image: the dark brown area and the area with the woodplanks have technically the same material]

[image: UV's (the curve one doesnt even appear)]

Comment: could you please show how your UVs look like?

Comment: I added a picture. As it appears, the part which was made out of curves doesnt even appear on the UV Editor.

Comment: so what does it give if you unwrap this part again?

Comment: Could you please add the .blend file?

Comment: Sounds as if you may need to recalculate the normals.

Comment: works! If I go in Editmode, select a face which wont work and do "Rightclick -> UV Unwrap Faces -> Unwrap" it shows the texture normally! Thanks alot!